# Pattern matching over entries of an array/split

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I'm implementing a type of BSP tree in Rust, and I am wanting to write a function that tells which side of a parent node a node belongs to. This is what I have

```
enum Side {
    L = 0,
    R = 1,
}

enum RegionKind {
    Split { 
        subregion: [Option<Rc<Region>>; 2],
    },
    Client{ 
        window: i32,
    },
}

struct Region {
    kind: RegionKind,
    container: Option<Rc<Region>>,
    tags: u8,
}

impl Region {
    fn from(&self) -> Option<Side> {
        if let RegionKind::Split{subregion,..} = &self.container.as_ref()?.kind {
            match &subregion[0] {
                None => None,
                Some(r) => if eq(Rc::<Region>::as_ptr(&r),self) {
                    Some(Side::L)
                } else {
                    None
                }.or_else(|| { match &subregion[1] {
                    None => None,
                    Some(r) => if eq(Rc::<Region>::as_ptr(&r),self) {
                        Some(Side::R)
                    } else {
                        None
                    }
                }})
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

There are currently two things in place that are making this function quite the behemoth.

1. I need to repeat the check on on subregion[0] and subregion[1]. I would really like to be able to return the `Side` of the index (given that L = 0 and R = 1 like shown in the enum declaration) and be able to combine these into one, hence why I am asking to match over the elements of the array. Something like how you use `Some(r) => ...` to unbox the `r` out of the `Some`
2. I need to check if the `RegionKind` is `Split`. I can assert that any Region's `container` will always have `RegionKind::Split` as their `kind`, so I would like to be able to eliminate the `if let else` entirely (I would prefer to `panic!()` in that else block if I must have it as well, but the compiler gets upset about return types so I need to add the `None` at the end anyways, which just ends up getting marked as unreachable)

I figure there's probably some arcane Rust syntax that can make this much more concise and I just don't know it or don't know how to employ it here. This same function can be a single line macro in C.

Comment: How would it be written as a one-liner in C?

Comment: `#define from(x) (((x)->container->subregion[L] == (x)) ? L : R)`, I think there is some unsafety with nullptr checks, but that is obviously going to be the difference between Rust and C. I used this macro with the same data structure in C and I never ran into issues, though.

Comment: There is an important distinction between this macro and your code: this macro will default to `R` when the parent is not this parent, and your code will return `None`. If you are willing to give up on this, you can make your code nicer: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35d2b5d62f3231b81624d0d756aa4de7. let chains can improve this a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. a `Region`'s `container` will always be its parent in the tree structure (otherwise the whole data structure is broken). The difference with the Rust code is that there is not risk of a null pointer dereference if this function is called on the root node, which was a concern in the C code (that I always avoided, but with the rust code it wouldn't have to be thought about)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Your extra handling is redundant and the code I provided is equivalent. If you want to handle the case of a non-existing parent, then https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=439662c35a28710f248c17f63f6211bf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move some stuff to other functions.

```rust
impl RegionKind {
    // you may want to make this a method on `Region` instead
    fn subregion(&self) -> Option<&[Option<Rc<Region>>; 2]> {
        if let RegionKind::Split { subregion, .. } = self {
            Some(subregion)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl Region {
    fn eq_then_side(&self, r: &Region, side: Side) -> Option<Side> {
        eq(self, r).then_some(side)
    }
}
```

Then you can write it concisely.

```rust
pub fn from(&self) -> Option<Side> {
    let [sub_left, sub_right] = self.container.as_ref()?.kind.subregion().unwrap();

    sub_left
        .as_ref()?
        .eq_then_side(self, Side::L)
        .or_else(|| sub_right.as_ref()?.eq_then_side(self, Side::R))
}
```

Note that if you ever find yourself matching an `Option`, especially with `None => None`, you can almost certainly use an [`Option` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) instead, usually `map` or `and_then`. In this case, `?` will work since the two `None` values are being returned.

I believe you don't need to use `Rc::as_ptr` since you are never using the pointer for reading, and the `Rc` is never dropped anyway. You can just derive the pointer straight from the shared reference.

What you said about panics isn't true. You can always replace an expression with a panic unless that return is needed for type inference, but since you have an explicit return type, that does not apply here. I've used `unwrap` above as the panic.

If you wanted to make it truly one expression, you can do that, but I wouldn't recommend it since it becomes too complex.

```rust
pub fn from(&self) -> Option<Side> {
    self.container
        .as_ref()?
        .kind
        .subregion()
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        .map_while(|sub| sub.as_ref())
        .zip([Side::L, Side::R])
        .find_map(|(sub, side)| sub.eq_then_side(self, side))
}
```

You could also replace `[Side::L, Side::R]` with `(0u8..).map(|n| Side::try_from(n).unwrap())` and implement `TryFrom<u8> for Side`, but I wouldn't bother when you only have two variants. Rust doesn't provide many convenient uses for explicit enum discriminants.

Comment: Between my post and your comment, I altered the structure a bit to use `RefCell`, and had to alter your solution accordingly but it works! I ended up using your final implementation as a single expression because it made the borrow checker happy (method chains like that tend to be safe in that regard), but I did end up implementing `subregion` on `Region` instead, like you mentioned. THanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that if we have a parent we are either the left child or the right, we can avoid the check on the right (like in C). This simplifies the code:

```rust
fn from(&self) -> Option<Side> {
    let RegionKind::Split {
        subregion: [sub_left, _],
        ..
    } = &self.container.as_ref()?.kind
    else {
        unreachable!();
    };
    if let Some(sub_left) = sub_left {
        if eq(&**sub_left, self) {
            return Some(Side::L);
        }
    }
    Some(Side::R)
}
```

This is still longer than C for two reasons: first, in Rust you use reference  counting and the layout of `Rc` is not guaranteed, so you cannot just compare `self` to `Option<Rc>` assuming `None` will return `false`. Second, you need to handle the case of `RegionKind::Client`, which you don't handle in C. The handling of a root node (no parent), however, is given almost for free, thanks to the `?` operator.